# Multi-Threaded Server Chat Java - Connecting but no messages

Tags: java, multithreading, serversocket

Trying to build a simple multi-threaded chat server that runs via command prompt. The clients do connect to the server and the server will hold multiple clients, however when trying to send messages from one client to the other, or even notifying a client of another user logging in, nothing comes up on the client command prompt.

```
public class Server {
private static ServerSocket servSock;
private static Socket clientSock;
private static ArrayList<ClientThread> clientList;
private static int IDcount = 0;


public static void main(String args[]){
      // Get command line arguments.
      if (args.length != 3) {
         System.out.println("Required arguments: server port, block duration, timeout");
         return;
      }
      int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
      int blockDur = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
      int timeout = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);

      try{
      servSock = new ServerSocket(port);
      clientList = new ArrayList<ClientThread>();
      }
      catch(IOException ex){
          System.err.println(ex);
      }


      while (true) {
        try {
          clientSock = servSock.accept();
          ClientThread thread = new ClientThread(clientSock);
          clientList.add(thread);
          thread.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          System.out.println(e);
        }
      }
    }

private synchronized static void broadcast(String msg){
    System.out.print(msg);
    for(int i = 0; i < clientList.size(); i++){
        ClientThread client = clientList.get(i);
        client.send(msg);
    }

}

synchronized static void unlist(int id){
for(int i = 0; i < clientList.size(); i++){
    ClientThread thread = clientList.get(i);
    if(thread.id == id){
        clientList.remove(i);
        return;
        }
    }
}

static class ClientThread extends Thread {
    Socket sock;
    BufferedReader tIn;
    PrintWriter tOut;

    int id;
    String username;
    String msg;

    ClientThread(Socket sock){
        id = IDcount++;
        this.sock = sock;
        try{
            tIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
            tOut = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
            username = tIn.readLine();
            broadcast(username + " logged in");
        }
        catch(IOException ex){
            System.err.println(ex);
        }
    }

    public void run(){
        boolean loggedIn = true;
        while(loggedIn){
            try{
                msg = tIn.readLine();
            }
            catch (IOException ex){
                System.err.println(ex);
            }
            String[] parts = msg.split("\\s",2);
            String type = parts[0];
```

Client code is similar

```
public class Client{
private static Socket clientSock;
private static BufferedReader in;
private static PrintWriter out;
private static Scanner scan;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      if (args.length != 2) {
             System.out.println("Required arguments: server IP, server port");
             return;
          }
      String host = args[0];
      int port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

      clientSock = new Socket(host, port);
      in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSock.getInputStream()));
      out = new PrintWriter(clientSock.getOutputStream());
      scan = new Scanner(System.in);

      new ListenFromServer().start();
      boolean online = true;

      System.out.println("Enter your username:");
      String username = scan.nextLine();

      out.println(username);

      while(online){
          System.out.println("> ");
          String msg = scan.nextLine();
          String[] parts = msg.split("\\s");
          String type = parts[0];
          send(msg);
          if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("logout")){
              online = false;
          }


      }
      logoff();
}

      static void send(String msg) throws IOException{
          out.println(msg);
      }

      private static void logoff() throws IOException{
              in.close();
              out.close();
              scan.close();
              clientSock.close();
      }

     static class ListenFromServer extends Thread{
         public void run(){
             while(true){
                 try{
                     String msg = in.readLine();
                     System.out.println(msg);
                 }
                 catch(IOException ex){
                     System.err.println(ex);
                 }
             }
         }
     }

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code?  Also, your catching errors where you don't want to.

Answer (score 0):

When you send data with `PrintWriter.println()`, data write to buffer. You must call `PrintWriter.flush()` after `println` to send data to or from the server immediately.

And when you call `username = tIn.readLine();` in ClientThread constructor, you block main-thread, because constructor calls in main-thread. So, while connected user won't send username, other clients can't connect.